# C# to Excel - Custom formatting?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-2003

Is there a way to apply custom formatting if value in cell is less then 0 set color to be RED.

I know how to do this by setting color for individual cell, but what I have is 8 reports with lots of cells and I just want to apply this rule on whole sheet, so I don't have to do it for each cell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look into conditional formatting.  Here's a related question that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969353/excel-interop-conditional-formatting

Comment: For negative number you can use a custom cell format like `0.00;[Red]-0.00`

Comment: Nice man, I didn't know that, cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do it in interop lower than 12 version.

I have changed version of **interop.excel** to 14 for Excel 2010 and its working with

```
FormatCondition f = (FormatCondition)r.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
                                                       XlFormatConditionOperator.xlLess, 0, misValue, misValue,
                                                       misValue, misValue, misValue);
            f.Font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

**[FormatCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.formatcondition.aspx)** property